Recorded Video Ending Prematurely with WebSocket and FFmpeg
I am working on a screen recording application where it allows users to record their screen and I use websocket to send their bytes data in real time to my FastAPI Python server. The  bytes are sent every 2 second and I use FFmpeg to keep saving the bytes in the output MP4 video file.
Problem: Everything was working fine when I had the server running on my local machine, however, I just deployed the server to EC2 instance us-ease-1 and when I try to record the videos, the videos are really short, IE, if I record a 30 second video, it only has the video for 3 second. Sometimes it saves 90% of the video and sometimes less. I am not sure what is the problem here.
I have been trying to debug the code for the past few days, but with no success
Here is my code :
FRONTEND
const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
            mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=H264',
            videoBitsPerSecond: 8000000
        });

recorder.ondataavailable = (e: BlobEvent) => {
    socketRef.socket.send(e.data)
}

And here is my python code :-
@router.websocket("/stream")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket, token: str = Query(...), videoId: str = Query(...), authorize: AuthJWT = Depends()):
    await manager.connect(websocket)
    dataNumber = 1

    recordingFile = os.path.join(temp_dir, f"recording_{videoId}.mp4")

    command = [
        'ffmpeg', 
        '-y',
        '-i', 
        '-', 
        '-codec:v', 
        'copy', 
        '-f', 'mp4',
        recordingFile,
    ]

    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    try:
        while True:
            try:
                data = await websocket.receive_bytes()
                if not data:
                    break
                process.stdin.write(data)
                await websocket.send_json({"chunkNumber": dataNumber, "status": 200})
                dataNumber = dataNumber + 1
            except RuntimeError:
                break      
    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        print(f"Client disconnected: {websocket.client.host}")
    finally:
        manager.disconnect(websocket)

        # Close stdin to signal EOF
        process.stdin.close()

        # Wait for FFmpeg to finish processing
        process.wait()

        # Ensure that the process is terminated
        process.terminate()  

I also get this error in the console :-

Editor's note: Text is auto-extracted by an AI (ie: may not be 100% correct)
libpostproc 57. 3.100/57. 3.100
Input #6, matroska, webm, from 'fd:':
Metadata:
encoder: Chrome
Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p(tv, bt789, progressive), 1920x1080, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 30
.30 fps, 56 tbr, 1k tbn (default)

Output #8, mp4, to /tmp/recording_d367d8d3-60de-483e-bf29-1849841b82f3.mp4':
Metadata:
encoder: Lavf60.16.100
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [
SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 38.30 fps, 56 tbr, 16k tbn (default)
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0> #0:6 (copy)
Client disconnected: 127.0.0.189 bitrate=3374.0kbits/s speed=0.999x
[matroska, webm @ 8x61e88988f3c0]
9493864 (0x98dd68)
[out#0/mp4 @ 0x61e8898cc488] video:9263kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams: 9kB global headers: 8kB muxing overhead: 0
.143342%
size= 9276kB time=00:00:21.85 bitrate=3476.8kbits/s speed=1.08x
INFO:
connection closed
INFO: 127.0.0.1:52546 "POST /api/process HTTP/1.1" 200 ок


I'm not a Python guy, but I'd assume receive_bytes isn't going to have anything for you in between messages.  Also, you didn't show how you started the MediaRecorder, but I'm guessing you've set the timeslice parameter so it's going to return data periodically?  As for why the variability, it's possible that little changes from frame to frame, in which case the MediaRecorder may emit very little (or even no) data.

@Brad, in media recorder, recorder.start(2000) would send data automatically every two seconds. I am confused with the fact that why does everything worked fine on my local machine and not on the VM running on the cloud?
There are potentially two problems I guess, 1. because of the distance between the server and the user
2. Or maybe there is something from my end that causing this problem

You need to verify that your WebSocket isn't closing, and that your method of reading the WebSocket binary data will continue to stay open and keep reading beyond a single WebSocket message.  I don't know about your cloud setup... if you have a reverse proxy in the mix, that can cause side effects for Web Sockets depending on how its configured.

@Brad Does MediaRecorder care about this setting mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=H264'? I also wonder what codec's data they are really putting into the output MP4 with their -codec:v copy option, especially for when their code is running in Chrome or Firefox.

@VC.One Yeah, MediaRecorder uses that.  And, H.264 is in-use here as indicated by the FFmpeg CLI output.
